# Direct connection w/ ethernet cable

Tags: networking, routing, ethernet, iproute

*This is for "research" not pragmatic purposes -- I want to know how this is supposed to work, since my guess below does not.  In other words, I do not want an answer that involves `/etc/network/interfaces` or anything else distro specific, or NetworkManager.*

**Please do not close this as a duplicate of a question which provides such answers.**

I'm trying to connect two GNU/Linux systems w/ a regular (not cross-over) ethernet cable.  Rumor has it that this should not be a problem now-a-days.

What I tried to do is add a private IP for the interface on both machines:

```
ip addr add 10.0.0.1 dev eth0
```

And `10.0.0.2` on the other machine.  Neither one is attached to a network that could be identified this way.

I then added routes back and forth:

```
ip route add 10.0.0.2 via 10.0.0.1
```

And vice versa.  Subsequently, the output of `ip addr` and `ip route` seems to be correct (see below).  As per John's comment, I also tried this without adding any route; in this case the ping simply times out.

Both machines have iptables wide open; INPUT, OUTPUT, and FORWARD are ACCEPT with no rules.

But this is what happens when I try a ping:

```
> ping 10.0.0.2
PING 10.0.0.2 (10.0.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.0.0.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.0.1 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
```

Notice it's the local interface (10.0.0.1) that returns this.

What additional steps are needed here and/or where have I gone wrong?

---

The routing table after using `ip route ...` looks like:

```
default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan0 
10.0.0.2 via 10.0.0.1 dev eth0 
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.19
```

Sans `ip route ...`, it looks the same but without line 2.

---

Output from ethtool (both NICs are identical hardware) looks like:

```
ethtool eth0
Settings for eth0:
        Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
        Supported pause frame use: No
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
        Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                             100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
        Link partner advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
        Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Speed: 100Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Port: MII
        PHYAD: 1
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: on
        Supports Wake-on: pumbag
        Wake-on: d
        Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                               drv probe link
        Link detected: yes
```

The output from `ip a` for the ethernet NIC looks like:

```
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:f5:4f:7a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.2/32 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::ba27:ebff:fef5:4f7a/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: Why are you adding routes? You shouldn't need routes with the IPs you mention, as they (should be) on the same subnet. What does your routing table on each host look like immediately after adding the IP, and then after adding the route?

Comment: Even nowadays not every NIC has autosense, which you need on one side at least. IP doesn't matter, do you have a link? `ethtool eth0` shows something like `Link detected: yes` and show negotiated speeds etc.? How long is the cable - sometimes very short cables do not work well.

Comment: @John I've edited in the routing table below the original post.  I tried this without adding the route (or rather, by deleting it and the address and then resetting the address) and the ping just times out.

Comment: @frostschutz I've added the output from `ethtool` below the original question.

Comment: Could you please also add the output from `ip a` from one side.

Comment: @phk Okay, that's underneath `ethtool` stuff.

Comment: Even without explicitly adding a route, you should have an entry in your routing table for the 10. network. What does `ifconfig eth0` say after adding the IP? It almost looks like the link / interface isn't coming up properly.

Comment: @John I believe that would be the same as `ip a` (`ifconfig` isn't installed).

Comment: It's more common to add `10.0.0.x/24` instead of `.../32`, it should also give you the subnet route automagically.

Comment: What happens if you run `ip link set eth0 up` immediately after the `ip add` command but before adding the routes? I know the `ip a` output shows the link already up, but somehow I don't trust it.

Comment: @frostschutz - actually, the default subnet for 10. networks is /8, not /24. Most systems will give you a /8 mask with a 10. address unless you explicitly specify otherwise, which isn't happening here.

Comment: @frostschutz Bingo.  I removed the address and added it again using `/24` explicitly.  `10.0.0.0/24` now appears in the routing table and the ping works.  If you want to add that as an answer I'll give you the tick; obviously not specifying anything sets `/32`, which causes a problem -- I did try this multiple times, and when the address ends up as `/32`, `10.0.0.0` is not in the routing table.

Comment: @John Trying `ip link set eth0 up` after `ip add` (without specifying `/24`, see my last comment) did not change anything with the routing table or the ping.

Comment: Sensibly enough, using `/8` works as well.

Comment: I knew why I asked for the `ip a` output. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As written in the comments, you need to fix the routing table.

The syntax `ip route add X via Y` is used for gateway traffic, i.e. if the traffic to `X` should be sent to
the (most time external address) `Y`. There need to be a extra route how `Y` 
could be reached. If `Y` is your own interface address
and you do not solve the problem otherwise, you create a loop and the routing
does not work.

What you need is that the traffic to the other host is sent directly via
the interface (not via a gateway). 
There many different possibilities, depending on the netmask you use:

```
ip r add 10.0.0.2/32 dev eth0    # only 10.0.0.2 should go via eth0
...
ip r add 10.0.0.0/8 dev eth0     # 10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255 should go via eth0
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that by default this:

```
ip addr add 10.0.0.1 dev eth0
```

Set a subnet mask of `/32`, meaning there could not be any other nodes on the subnet, and trying to set a route there with `via` amounted to nothing.

Using an explicit, saner mask:

```
ip addr add 10.0.0.1/24 dev eth0
```

Solves the problem; alternately see jofel's answer.